# setNeedsDisplay release subviews?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, subview, setneedsdisplay

If a custom view adds several subviews to itself based on a condition `if`, and later a `setNeedsDisplay` is called on this view where the condition is no longer `true` and thus these subviews are not created, are the "old" subviews automatically released from memory during the `drawRect`?

Or, should I worry about checking for the presence of subviews, releasing them, then `setNeedsDisplay`?

I guess ultimately my question is about the memory implications of `setNeedsDisplay`, if it effectively removes from memory the old view and its subviews and then essentially recreates the view from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-setNeedsDisplay just sets a flag that says "this view needs to be redrawn." As far as I know, it doesn't retain or release anything, or add or remove any subviews.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're worrying too much. Call -setNeedsDisplay when your app's state has changed in a way that requires a given view to be redrawn. If you subsequently remove that view from your view hierarchy, that shouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: i guess what i need to know is, if the view will be redrawn with -setNeedsDisplay, what happens to the memory occupied by any subviews of that view that will no longer be drawn after the -setNeedsDisplay? I'm wondering if I have to worry about managing the memory of subviews that will no longer be there.

Comment: First, -setNeedsDisplay only marks a view for redrawing, it doesn't actually do any drawing. Depending on what's going on in your app, -setNeedsDisplay could be called a dozen times before the view is actually redrawn. Second, when -drawRect: is called, the view will either have subviews or not. If it has any, those will be drawn. If not, they won't. Third, if you remove a view from its superview, the superview will release it. Last, don't remove a subview from inside -drawRect:. If that's still not clear, perhaps you could post some code or further describe the situation.

Comment: ok, thanks. i'm trying to understand the process before i add some code and do some significant work. currently, i have a method called by drawRect. in that method, i plan to add code that will `addSubview` - when setNeedsDisplay redraws the view, it sounds like even if that method will no longer `addSubview` due to changed conditions, those subviews will in fact still appear onscreen since setNeedsDisplay does not get rid of them.

Comment: Right -- setNeedsDisplay won't remove anything.